# Java build system with automatic dependency resolution

Tags: java

I am trying to get up to speed with Java after spending my last couple of years with Python and Perl. And boy is this hard! First of all, there's no easy to use build system that can do only what you want it to do without adding tons of boilerplate. Then, how to add dependencies to your project, how do you run junit tests from the build systems (say ant for example)? How can I make the build system download the dependencies on the fly (or can't I?)

Can I find some docs around that can get me up to speed with this without reading a couple of books ? I am trying to be "agile", but the comeback is hard.

Please feel free to close it if it is too subjective. Thanks!

Comment: So, let me get this straight... you're complaining that Java isn't python or perl? Some languages and platforms have a steep learning curve. How about you ask a specific question or show us a specific problem you've bumped into instead of stating the obvious that Java is not as simple as a dynamic agile scripting language?

Comment: As other have mentioned, you should look into Maven. It handles dependencies (including test-time only ones) and integrates well with just about all the Java IDEs. Really all you need is a proper directory structure and a proper `pom.xml`.

Comment: @Lior Cohen: no specific question, just wondering if anyone battled with this before and what was the approach here. And yes, it's hard coming from dynamic languages, but one step at a time should do it.

Comment: Just wondering though how Scala (SBT) and even Clojure (Leinigen) made it and it's so hard to do it for Java

Answer (score 2):

This question is close to textbook trolling... anyway.

There are a lot of build systems that resolve dependencies for you out there (maven, ant, buildr, etc).

I'd say go with [buildr](http://buildr.apache.org/) since you are familiar with scripting languages.

**NOTE**

Though many people pointed out maven, considering your background (perl, python, etc) that will make you hate java even more (it's a sea of `<XML>` out there dude!). Please consider buildr if you feel frustrated enough

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which build systems you've tried (other than ant). I feel either Maven or Gradle would meet your needs (although I think Maven might fail your "tons of boilerplate" test; it certainly fails mine).

Answer (score 0):

There are an awful lot of questions here. "Maven" is the Java build system that automatically downloads dependencies; it is based on Ant, which does everything else you ask about (running tests, etc).

If you want to use Maven, get started by using Maven's quickstart docs and examples.